# User login security. Session vs Mysql active users table

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

I'm thinking about security problems, made some questions, read some articles..... it's too difficult to get all information from all those articles with very different methods and put them in 1 place to have normal user login and user check system.

Today I've read about haveing mysql table with active users list instead of storing sessions.
As I understand sessions are too difficult to secure, and on the other hand mysql table I think is very easy to make.

For example, users loggs in. Instead of making some 'user' session, I can simply insert new data into active_users_table and add user ip there.

And on all pages I can ask client for ip, then go to mysql table check if such ip-user is logged in, if yes check what rights does the user have and give him corresponding  access.

**Question 1.** Isn't it simple ? easier to make then securing sessions?

**Question 2.** If this system is good enough so I could stop my research and construct site using this method question is how can I understand if the user is still active ? If he will press 'log out' button ok , I will log out him and delete his record from the table. But if he restarts his PC or something? how can I understand when the record will be available for destruction ?

**Question 3.** one guy told me to use mysqli instead of mysql commands when I'm working with database. Are they the same so I just have to add "i" to all my commands and it's ok, or mysqli is a bit different and needs some study ? and also why is it better ? WHy I cannot use normal mysql commands to which I got used to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session CAN BE and often IS stored in the database. So there is no session vs database. Session is a way to persist information between HTTP requests, as HTTP is stateless protocol.

The difference between session and your approach is that session relies on cookie, and you are relying on IP. But there can be multiple users with the same IP. So your approach is not secure, session is more secure.

The database is offered instead of the default file-saving mechanism from a security point of view, because in a shared environment other user can read the session files. Also, session in a database can scale easier, if you have a lot of active users.

You should care about session hijacking and session fixation attacks. None of these is related to how you are storing the session data.

Question 3 have nothing to do with the session and deserves own question. But mysqli is just the newer extension, and supports more functions. In most cases it's used exactly the same as the mysql functions.

Comment: but I've read many articles that session is not secure enough, and there were many methods how to secure it. On the other hand if I just write a record in mysql table without using session what do I lose ?

Comment: @David I've updated my answer with explanation. Please read it and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: session WAS good because u can write session start on each page and access session variable wherever u want. But session is not secure. On the other hand accessing mysql table on each page isn't that quick but I think it's easier. get IP from client, go to database, check if this user is logged in - done.

Comment: session is a mechanism. database is a storage. So we just cannot talk about session vs database. Read @Jacco answer, it made good point.

Comment: Ok i've read your new answer. That's bad :( I mean you are writing right but it is bad that things are not simple :( can u give me some links with examples of code how all things are done correctly ? cause there were many different methods...

Answer (score 4):

NO, it's not that simple. *(if it was that simple, we would do it like that : )*

You need something that uniquely identifies the user. IP won't do. Also, it needs to be non-predicatble, hard to hijack, not show up in server logs, etc, etc, etc.

The current accepted standard is: use a long, high entropy random token and store it in a cookie.
For PHP, use PHP's build in session functions.

Security is a very delicate area of expertise, the best advice is: **do not invent your own security scheme.**

You can store the session data in a database instead of in a file, no problem. It *might* even add to the overall security. But then again, it might just ass well not do anything at all. (it depends on may factors)

Comment: can u provide some useful links with example code about how all things are made correctly ? cause i'm stuck here trying to secure the session studding  one method and then reading that there are many other threats....

Comment: Well, unfortunately, it's not that simple. My session handler class, although just a wrapper around PHP's buildin functions, is quite complex.